# JSSOR Carousel with text possible?

Tags: jssor

Is it possible to make a carousel with text?? like this http://amazingcarousel.com/

Yeah you got carousel with text but the image there is set as background, I need the images to be set in img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah for sure.

You can place everything in slide. You can define content slide as follows,

```
<div><!-- Any HTML Content Here --></div>
```

Reference: [Define Slides Html Code](http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html)